# AnyLogic - How can I prioritize a pool of employees with Quality Matrix?

Tags: matrix, simulation, anylogic, event-simulation

I have a pool of 10 employees. These employees are to operate two machines. 7 of these employees can operate machine A better than the remaining 3, who can operate machine B better.

Example: Worker XYZ works on machine A, on which he is better. On machine B, however, one worker is missing, because all 3 workers there are overloaded. Now worker XYZ should leave his prioritized work on machine A and go to machine B. As soon as the workload there becomes less again, worker XYZ should return to the prioritized machine A.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this kind of prioritization? In the best case still a prioritization on the basis of a quality matrix, so that one could take not only boolean values, but also double as value?

I had two approaches so far:

1.) create a single resource for each of the workers and do a function query for priority when a seize-block is received or.
2.) using the maintenance block in the different priorities for different tasks and try to assign them to the individual employees.

Unfortunately, I'm not really getting anywhere with either approach. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You may want to consider switching a purely agent-based approach where all this is modelled explicitly by yourself. While you probably can achieve your scenario here, it will be a lot more difficult to go beyond it with skill matrices, etc. The AnyLogic process blocks typically help with basic scenarios but you will always run into their capability limit. This seems one of them

Comment: Hi Benjamin, do you have any advice on how I can best read up on this? I am actually bound to a discrete simulation due to a problem definition, as my description of the example is just a strong simplification of the actual problem. 
I can't quite figure out how to implement your tip and where to look for information. Can you help me there? Here on SOF I haven't found any other threads on this topic either.

Comment: Not really, learn agent-based modelling is the best advice. Go through the tutorials, learn OOP... It is quite different to process blocks and needs a lot more coding and experience, but opens up a whole world of flexibility beyond those blocks